# Hilbert Space, anda Bessel’s inequality

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces, bessel-functions

could you please help me in this matter

question
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $B=\{e_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset H$  be a sequence of orthonormal vectors. Prove that $e_{n} \rightharpoonup 0$

I'm having trouble applying bassel inequality, because I do not know if we consider this normal sequence as a replacement only for the orthogonal system.

any help be welcome, thanks

Comment: It is enough to restrict yourself to the separable Hilbert subspace $B^{\perp\perp}$.  The $B^\perp$ doesn't contribute any nonzero functionals you care.

Comment: You seem to know exactly what to do... Given a functional $\tau=\langle\cdot,x\rangle$, Bessel gives $\sum_n|\langle e_n,x\rangle|^2\leq\Vert x\Vert^2$, so $|\tau(e_n)|^2=|\langle e_n,x\rangle|^2\to 0$....

Comment: you say to define an T: $H \rightarrow H$ given by  $T(x) = \sum x_{n} <x, e_{n}>e_{n} $ and show that it is compact ?

Comment: You should review Riesz's representation theorem and what the symbol "$e_n\rightharpoonup 0$" means, as it seems you're having trouble identifying what needs to be proved.

Comment: But $x_{n} \rightarrow  x \in H $ if only if  $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x $